# Pause spotify playback intent

Tags: android, spotify

I am looking for a way to pause Spotify playback. I have tried searching, and using the AudioManager, but I believe that only works if it is part of your activity. Does anyone know a way to pause Spotify playback?

Answer (score 0):

[How to stop or pause Pandora and Spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326017/how-to-stop-or-pause-pandora-and-spotify)

That issue is similar and shows how to pause and stop most media players.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works best:

```
       Intent pauseSpotify = new Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY");
       pauseSpotify.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
       sendBroadcast(pauseSpotify);
```

Essentially, what you are doing is, creating a new intent which action is the built in "PLAY" action from the spotify app. Next you set the package and finally call the intent.

I got the idea from an [article](https://androidtrix.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/tasker-spotify-plug-load-and-play/) and applied it to normal android.

Answer (score 0):

```
//play
Intent intent = new 
Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY");
   intent.putExtra("paused",true);
   intent.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
   sendBroadcast(intent);

//pause
Intent intent = new 
Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY");
   intent.putExtra("paused",false);
   intent.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
   sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I've analyzed Spotify's apk file and found the command file.
This would work perfectly on version 8.4.77
You can skip song by replacing "PLAY" to "NEXT".
I tried "PREVIOUS" but it didn't work, guessing it as spotify's default design.